# PackagesNotFoundError - rapids=24.02* for jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, package, nvidia, cudf

I want to install cudf

I used this command in a jupyter notebook and got this error for the current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/rapidsai
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
- https://conda.anaconda.org/nvidia
- defaults

!conda create --solver=libmamba -n rapids-24.02 -c rapidsai -c conda-forge -c nvidia  
rapids=24.02 python=3.10 cuda-version=11.8

Python version is correct
Cuda version is correct

Comment: Are you using linux? According to [here](https://anaconda.org/rapidsai/rapids) that is only available for linux. You should not be using a exclamation point with conda install. Run `%conda install rapidsai::rapids` (feel free to try to specify the solver) based on [here](https://anaconda.org/rapidsai/rapids) and current best practice to use `install` commands in modern Jupyter. In 2019 the `%conda install`  was added to insure the installation occurs in the enviornment where the kernel backing the active notebook is running. ...

Comment: <continued> The exclamation point doesn't do that and can lead to issues. See more about the modern `%conda install` command [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). [The second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and note that it says, "Include any error messages".

Comment: <continued> The entire error result should be shown because it will contain more information than you are providing with the only tidbit of information in the title.

Comment: Your command looks fine, it matches https://docs.rapids.ai/install. More error output is needed to diagnose the problem. I believe the `!` is used to run a shell command inside a Jupyter notebook.